# {app.exe!_com_error::`vector deleting destructor'(unsigned int)}

Tags: c++

I am getting exception while creating MSMQqueue in Visual Studio 2017, find the code and exception details below:

```
Exception details :
app.exe!`queue::CreateQueue'::`1'::catch$3() Line 56    C++ Symbols loaded.
```

Please suggest the queue for implementing serial port read and write.

**queue.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MSMQ_Queue.h"
#import "mqoa.dll"
using namespace MSMQ;

queue::queue()  {}
queue::~queue() {}

HRESULT queue::CreateQueue(WCHAR *wszPathName)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    if (wszPathName == NULL)
    {
        return MQ_ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER;
    }

    try
    {
        IMSMQQueueInfoPtr pInfo("MSMQ.MSMQQueueInfo");

        // Set the queue's path name and label.  
        pInfo->PathName = wszPathName;
        pInfo->Label = "TestQueue";

        // Create the queue.  
        **pInfo->Create();**//Hitting exception at this point

        WCHAR wszMessage[1024] = { 0 };     
    }
    catch (const _com_error& comerr)
    {
        hr = comerr.Error();            
        WCHAR wszMessage[2048] = { 0 };
    }
    return hr;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include"queue.h"    
#include <stdio.h>      // for printf

int main()
{    
    wchar_t name[] = L".\\vniqueue";

    queue msmqueue; 
    //CoInitialize(0);
    OleInitialize(NULL);

    HRESULT returnValue = msmqueue.CreateQueue(name);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

[Exception create queue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSs92.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider to visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to check out how to ask good questions on SO and get help answers from the community.

Comment: Do not post screenshots, post text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found solutions for this..

I have given public path instead of private pat. Changed “.//queuename” to .//private$//queuename”.